# How do I make a pretty UITextView that expands as needed (like the one used in the SMS app)?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uikit, uitextview

It should:

- Expand vertically whenever new lines are added with the return key.
- Wrap long lines and expand vertically for wrapped lines as needed too.
- Have a nice pretty border just like UITextField.
- Support placeholder text just like UITextField.
- Support friendly actions like UITextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20/wiki). They have something like this.